# ValueError: time data '2006–01–01' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Tags: python, pandas, time

I got error messages: `ValueError: time data '2006–01–01' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'`. I'm not clear that '2006-01-01' seems to be the correct format to me.

```
import numpy as np #python library for scientific computing
import pandas as pd #python library for data manipulation and analysis
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #python library for charting
import yfinance as yf #python library to scrap data from yahoo finance
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr #extract data from internet sources into pandas data frame

yf.pdr_override()

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo('^DJI', start="2006–01–01")
data2 = pdr.get_data_yahoo("MSFT", start="2006–01–01")
data3 = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AAPL", start="2006–01–01")
data4 = pdr.get_data_yahoo("BB.TO", start="2006–01–01")

ax = (data['Close'] / data['Close'].iloc[0] * 100).plot(figsize=(15, 6))
(data2['Close'] / data2['Close'].iloc[0] * 100).plot(ax=ax, figsize=(15,6))
(data3['Close'] / data3['Close'].iloc[0] * 100).plot(ax=ax, figsize=(15,6))
(data4['Close'] / data5['Close'].iloc[0] * 100).plot(ax=ax, figsize=(15,6))

plt.legend(['Dow Jones', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'Blackberry'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The format is using hyphens, not en-dashes. The data does use en dashes, though.

Comment: Man too many types of dashes

Comment: The various kinds of dashes, historically, had well-defined uses. Computer usage reduced everything to hyphens when there was limited space in character sets. With Unicode, the dashes are making a comeback.

Answer (score 2):

Your format uses hyphens (U+002d). Your `start` argument, though, is using en dashes (U+2013).